# Array.find() isn't working on objects but when I do it separately on specific object it works

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object Cell and then I draw multiple cells on canvas which creates grid, but later I have to acces neighbors of every cell and arrayOfCells.find isn' working how it should (1. and 2. idndex returns undefined). 
PS: I have checked if the cell im testing it on is in the middle.

```
let cellWidth = 25;

class Cell {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x * cellWidth;
        this.y = y * cellWidth;
        this.width = cellWidth;
        this.neighbors = [
            cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x && cell.y === this.y - this.width),
            cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x + this.width && cell.y === this.y),
            cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x && cell.y === this.y + this.width),
            cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x - this.width && cell.y === this.y)
        ];
    }
    
}
// Array of the cells
let cells = [];

// Creating Cells

for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
            cells.push(new Cell(x, y));
        }
    }
```

Comment: um, unclear how it should find elements yet to be created.... You need to rethink this whole neighbors thing. First one is created.... lets find the neighbors.... It is like being the first one at a party and you yell "HEY BOB WHERE ARE YOU?" And you expect Bob to answer.... but he is not since he is still on the bus to the party.

Comment: Rather implement neighbors as a class method that can be called to return neighbors after all are created.

Comment: Since you search your neighbors in the constructor of `Cell`, you can only find those neighbors that are already created, but not those that will be created later. Either search your neighbors in a separate step (after all cells are created) or change your logic so that each newly created cell introduces itself to its already existing neighbors, so they can update their neighborhood references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick snippet moving your neighbor logic to a method and accessing it with a `.neighbors` getter. see: [Classes#Prototype_methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods)

```js
let cellWidth = 25;

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x * cellWidth;
    this.y = y * cellWidth;
    this.width = cellWidth;
  }

  // Getter
  get neighbors() {
    return this.calcNeighbors();
  }
  // Method
  calcNeighbors() {
    const neighborArr = [
      cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x && cell.y === this.y - this.width),
      cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x + this.width && cell.y === this.y),
      cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x && cell.y === this.y + this.width),
      cells.find(cell => cell.x === this.x - this.width && cell.y === this.y)
    ];
    return neighborArr;
  }

}
// Array of the cells
let
  rows = 5,
  cols = 5,
  cells = [];

// Creating Cells
for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    cells.push(new Cell(x, y));
  }
}

console.log(cells[5].neighbors)
```